# How to override default value of parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have the following function signature:

```
question: (question_id, onComplete, use_redis = true) ->
```

I assume that I can override the `use_redis` parameter to be false, but everything I have tried hasn't worked yet.  Is this possible to do if I am defining my `onComplete` callback inline?  This is what my call to the function looks like:

```
Summaryresults.question 1, (summary) ->
    answer_data.summary = summary
    done()
```

I've tried adding `false` several different ways, but nothing works.  Do I need to define my callback function somewhere else and then reference that rather than defining it inline in order to override `use_redis`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should work that way:

```
Summaryresults.question 1, (summary) ->
  answer_data.summary = summary
  done()
, false
```

the first param is the id, the second your callback function, the third setting use_redis to false

edit - my solution for changing the api:

```
question: (id, options...) ->
  [use_redis, onComplete] = options
  if typeof use_redis is "function"
    onComplete = options
    use_redis = true
```

and you should always put your callback as the LAST argument when calling this function:

without use_redis-param:

```
Summaryresults.question 1, (summary) ->
  answer_data.summary = summary
  done()
```

with use_redis-param:

```
Summaryresults.question 1, false, (summary) ->
  answer_data.summary = summary
  done()
```

Comment: Ahhh, there we go.  That was the one way i hadn't tried.  I'll accept in 2 mins

Comment: That API is just as cryptic. It marginally helps with syntax, but you still have no idea what it represents.

Comment: this is how it is almost always done in most (good) node.js modules. i really like the idea of passing the callback always as last argument. and i think jQuery does it the same!?! i prefer it over passing stuff as an object. just let abe choose...

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you want a callback to be the last argument, because the syntax gets wonky otherwise.

So why not change your API?

```
question: (question_id, options = {}) ->
  onComplete = options.onComplete
  useRedis = options.useRedis ? true
  # ...

Summaryresults.question 1,
  useRedis: false
  onComplete: ->
    answer_data.summary = summary
    done()
```

See how much more readable that is?

---

But that said, you can invoke with a funky comma in just the right spot

```
Summaryresults.question 1, (summary) ->
  answer_data.summary = summary
  done()
, false
```

Which compiles to:

```
Summaryresults.question(1, function(summary) {
  answer_data.summary = summary;
  return done();
}, false);
```

---

Or Perhaps

```
hollaback = (summary) ->
  answer_data.summary = summary
  done()

Summaryresults.question 1, hollaback, false
```

Comment: Yeah that fixed it thanks.  It does look a little weird with the callback in the middle.

Comment: @AbeMiessler See my update which contains a suggestion to alter you API to make this suck less.

Comment: i dont like the way you changed the api (the callback in an object). ill provide a solution in my answer.

Comment: @hereandnow78 Why not? I'll admit unnamed boolean arguments are a _huge_ pet peev of mine. You just never ever know what they do without looking up something in the docs. Passing arguments in an objects allows you to give them context, and it's how nearly everyone of the mainstream Ajax helper libraries is designed.

Comment: i just like to put the callback as last-param. of course your solution works and is clean code, it is just a matter of preference ;-)

Comment: Interesting, there are actually a number of functions defined this way in the code I am working with.  If I implemented it with the options object would it be possible to call this function with no callback defined?  I was thinking I like having the callback as it's own parameter because then you can't forget to pass it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Absolutely optional.  If you call the callback with the `?` operator it will only execute it if exists. Checkout this example: http://tinyurl.com/az8f7bu